# CSPF Neighbor configuration

Tags: solace

I have a question about CSPF Neighbor configuration.

I've tried to configure CSPF Neighbors on several AWS VMRs. All have opened through AWS rules port 55555, which is the default for CSPF neighbors. However, for some reason I did succeed on creating just the first neighbors.

When I've tried to repeat the process on different VMRs I didn't get a correct configuration and they show up as Connecting or even Shutdown.

The questions are:

1. Is there any restriction in SolAdmin Evaluation version for this type of configuration?
2. If my local VMRs have opened port 55555 for all, why is it that I only get the right configuration through the AWS internal IPs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any restriction in SolAdmin Evaluation version for this type of configuration?

No. This is not related to SolAdmin, which is the GUI for VMR instances.

> If my local VMRs have opened port 55555 for all, why is it that I only get the right configuration through the AWS internal IPs.

You need to open both ports 55555, and 55556 in your firewall.
These are the default ports for data and routing control.